# Expected time in markov mouse problem

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

**Here is the problem**
A mouse trap is placed in room 1 of the house with the pictured floor plan. Each time the
mouse comes into room 1, he is trapped with probability p = 0.1. If he is not trapped, he
leaves each room by one of its exits, chosen at random. Suppose that the mouse starts in Room 5, find the number of expected steps that the
mouse in Room 4 for the first time.

[image: Floor plan]

**My question is,** what is the "expected steps"? I think it should be infinite. When the mouse is in room 5, he has only one option to go to room 3. However, if he goes to room 3, he can turn to room 6 and just go back and forth or somewhere in the left side instead of going to room 4. The same for the right side.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me.  Is it to find the expected number of steps for the mouse to visit room $4$ for the first time? If so, then, yes, that expected number of steps is infinite, because there's definitely a positive probability that it will *never* reach that room.

Comment: when mouse is trapped is it trapped forever? or just one step?
If it's forever then there is non zero prob that mice will never reach 4

Comment: Well, I don't understand the question too. However, I've found a similar question at https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/150/takis_exercises.pdf (the 15th question). They do ask for " expected time" to return to room 1 in part e, thus I think it may be some mathematical terms that I don't know. That's why I asked this question :(

Comment: Imagine there is no trap in room 1: the mouse would come there an infinite number of times. With this probability $1/10$ to be caught, it will be caught in a finite number of steps (more exactly, I should add: "A.S.", Almost Surely)